# Area 51 layout not showing correctly on IE10 when zoomed out

Tags: bug, area-51, design

When I visit Area 51, the sidebar is shown above the content. It appears like this on IE10, it doesn't have this problem on other browsers that I have tried.

[image]

**EDIT:** To repro, you need to have to be zoomed out. Viewing at 95% zoom should be sufficient to reproduce the bug.

Comment: Oh, they make browsers other than Chrome???  :-P

Comment: [Cannot reproduce on IE 10](http://i.stack.imgur.com/toIEs.png)

Comment: [Can't repro either](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kSEkd.jpg) - marking as can't repro.

Comment: @Sklivvz We've figured out how to repro. Please reconsider.

Comment: Done. I think we are basically hitting a IE bug now (as zoom should "just work")

Comment: @Sklivvz The question is still tagged with [tag:status-norepro].

Comment: @PeterOlson where did you see that? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is reproducible only when you are zoomed out of the page (by around **5%**). Here are the related screenshots:

[image: At 95%]

<sub>At 95% zoom</sub>

[image: At 100%]

<sub>At 100% zoom</sub>